# Redshift query to count number of tickets watching by the users except the ones they created

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

We have 2 tables in our ticketing system. In this system, users can create tickets and any number of users can watch one or more tickets.

For which, we have set up 2 tables:

1. To store watch info - `watch_table`
2. To store ownership info - `ownership_table`

```
watch_table

ticket_id | watched_by
=======================
t1        | u1
t2        | u2
t2        | u1


ownership_table
ticket_id | owned_by
=====================
t1        | u1
t2        | u2
```

I want to extract the count of watches per user. But, exclude the watches on their own tickets.

For instance, in the above example the output should be:

```
output:

user_id | count
================
u1      | 1
u2      | 0
```

I can create a query using sub-queries to do this. Something like below:

```
select watched_by as user_id, count(*) from watch_table wt where
(select count(*) from ownership_table where owned_by = wt.watched_by and ticket_id = wt.ticket_id) = 0
group by watched_by
```

My question is how can I do this with joins and which one is more performant?

Comment: That query doesn't do what you're describing. It gives watchers who don't own anything.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=19901f70822260cc943e6e51b42c7fbe

Comment: I have updated. Missed one condition.

Comment: You can't correlate on that column after grouping. I already showed an answering the link above.

Comment: What about the performance of sub-query vs join?

Comment: Presumably there can be watchers who don't own anything? See comparison: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=98ea9e767d199e33e406f539a4fa2a38

Comment: The two approaches are probably equivalent.

Comment: Sorry, your subquery there would basically work. But you wouldn't get back any results for users who only watched their own tickets.

Comment: Yes, agree. I do not need them :) either 0 or no record is fine. Just shown that in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select w.userid, count(o.ticketid)
from watches w left join owners o
    on o.ticketid = w.ticketid and o.userid <> w.userid
group by w.userid
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=19901f70822260cc943e6e51b42c7fbe

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample data you can probably do this with an `outer join`

```
select t.owned_by as User_Id, Count(w.ticket_id) as count
from ownership_table t 
left join watch_table w on w.watched_by=t.owned_by and w.ticket_Id != t.ticket_Id
group by t.owned_by
```

An alternative could be a correlated subquery:

```
select Owned_By as User_Id, (
    select Count(*)
    from watch_table w
    where w.watched_by=t.Owned_by and w.ticket_Id != t.ticket_Id
    )
from ownership_table t
```

Comment: I think you've got the logic backward.

Comment: I think the join conditions are not correct. But I get your idea. Thanks!

Comment: I got the expected results with a simple test, I don't think there's a public Fiddle for Redshift? Perhaps I didn't full understand however but hopefully you can tweak!